# Switching Views

Tags: iphone, view, switching

I have two XIb files and I need to switch between them with the swipe of a finger, like the native iphone weather app. does anyone know how to do this. please give some sample code if possible. thank you.  P.S I am programming in Objective-C.

Comment: It's better to use the title to describe the problem and the tags to describe the domain, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check following sample source?
**07e - FlipViewSwipe** in **C02 - Views.zip**
http://code.google.com/p/cookbooksamples/downloads/list